# Why is there a 'remove(key, value)' method in the Map interface?

Tags: java, dictionary

I just found out that `Map` exposes a method for "[[removing] the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to the specified value.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)". It is defined as:

```
default boolean remove(Object key, Object value)
```

I fail to come up with reasons to include this method in the interface of my own custom maps. I'm curious, why would anyone want to do this? Can someone provide an example of an algorithm irreplaceable by the default `remove(key)` (without the 'value' parameter)?

Comment: You don't have to include it as it comes with a default implementation.

Comment: Do not include anything in your interface you don't need or you don't know if you need it.

Comment: @Henry I never mentioned extending the Java `Map`. I was talking about designing my own custom maps, possibly outside of Java altogether.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's why I posted the question, to find possible usages of this specific part of the interface. Did you not understand this?

Comment: "I'm curious, why would anyone want to do this? Free rep for anyone who comes up with the most minimal example." `map.remove(k, v);`. I want to do this because it satisfies my requirements.

Comment: Good point @AndyTurner, I'll redefine the task.

Comment: I don't think the question is that bad tbh. No idea why it gets so many downvotes.

Comment: That being said, I mean it's basically just a `removeValue`. Just as `remove(key)` removes the key if it's present, this one removes the value of a specific key if it's present. I can't think of any scenario from the top of my head though. But if someone ever needs it, it's there I guess.

Comment: But this is my point, don't implement it if _you_ don't see a need for it. At least if you are creating the interface for your own use.

Comment: @Beko Feels good to have at least a single person who understands, much appretiated :) To the matter at hand: `remove(value)` somewhat does make sense, for example if the key-generating procedure would suddenly change and you could not find the corresponding `key` to your `value` anymore. But `remove(key, value)`? You need to have all the information: both `key`, and `value`, honestly, this makes no sense to me. "But if someone ever needs it, it's there I guess." - yeah, this is pretty much my current state. Which is suboptimal.

Comment: The problem with your question is also that if one came up with an example use case the validity of that use case would depend on what other methods you have in the interface or what can be done with stream for instance. So in this case a better question might be "How would remove(key, value) fit in with the rest of my interface?".

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Honestly, what does it matter whether *I see* something or *don't* see something. I am here to learn, not to show.

Comment: I just think implementing something you don't see a need for is a kind of over-engineering and that it's better to focus on the stuff that matters and make them as good as possible. But sure if this is only an academical question and you are doing this for fun then you can go ahead and implement anything only based on if you find it interesting or not.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If one came up with an example use case, the validity of that use case can be defended by that individual however said individual wishes, even using another parts of the interface or streams or whatever, really. As far as I can tell, I have placed no constraint on what the defense of the usage argument should contain.

Comment: Example: a flow where an object goes through different states and those states (value) are stored per object (key) in a Map. Once the end state has been reached the object can be removed from the map (another variant is a counter and a limit).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson After this comment, I hope the point of this question, that is, to find out whether there are thinkable non-trivial applications of `remove(key, value)` in a map ADT with the Java-defined implementation details, is clear to you. I know as a fact that I regularly fail to explain problems properly, so feel free to suggest question edits that fit this particular question of mine, apart of course from trying to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I appretiate the fact that you are the first person to suggest an actual example, but please post an answer, instead of a comment, so we can discuss that answer in a separate place.

Comment: Nvm my comments. I thought it was removing values, but after reading @Dorian's update and rechecking the docs I've seen that it actually removes the key. Sry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc of that method explains it:

> The default implementation is equivalent to, for this map:
>
> ```
>  if (map.containsKey(key) && Objects.equals(map.get(key), value)) {
>      map.remove(key);
>      return true;
>  } else
>      return false;
> ```
>
> The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization
> or atomicity properties of this method. **Any implementation providing
> atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its
> concurrency properties.**

In general, as long as you don't have atomicity guarantees, don't override it and use the default implementation above.

This is useful in concurrent programming when multiple threads access the same Map. You would need a `ConcurrentHashMap` which provides atomicity guarantees for `remove(Object, Object)`.

For example, smth like that (imagine `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cache` is shared between threads):

```
String key = ...;
String value = cache.get(key);
//long lasting operation
cache.remove(key, value);
```

During that "long lasting operation", another thread might have updated the value assigned to `key`. You only want the key to be removed if it is still assigned to the same value as before.

Comment: Well firstly, Javadoc explains absolutely nothing about potential usage, which is the whole and only topic of this question, and secondly, I never mentioned extending the Java `Map`, but rather designing my own custom maps, which could possibly differ substantially from the Java `Map`, or be designed in a different language. This question is about abstract design and interface of an ADT, the Map, and why would you ever want to `remove` by `key` only if there is an expected `value` at `map.get(key)`.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I added a sketch of an example. Hope it helps, cannot think of anything more concrete than that.

Comment: Great, didn't think of this. Good point, thank you for explaining.